# Google Sheets Timevalue

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to return the timevalue only from a date/time numerical string; error code:

=timevalue(44396.33333)

TIMEVALUE parameter '44396.33333' cannot be parsed to date/time.

I want to directly remove the date and return the time numerical value only.

I am aware that I can use time(hour(),minute(),0), but looking for something direct and efficient as base formula is lengthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the return to still be a numerical value, capable of being compared or used with the wide range of mathematical operators, you can use this:

`=MOD(A1,1)`

Then format the cell or range in the time format of your choice (e.g., **Format > Number > Time** or **Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number format >** *hh:mm*, etc.).

`MOD` returns the remainder of the first parameter after dividing by the second. When using `1` as the last parameter, we are left with only whatever decimal portion of a number existed. And since Google Sheets counts each day as 1 and time as a decimal portion of 1, this will produce the time portion only of a time-date.

The following produces the same result:

`=A1-INT(A1)`

That is "the entirety of A1 minus the integer portion of A1."

Comment: Glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=TEXT(A1; "hh:mm:ss")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Sometimes simple isn't easy. For anyone else, replace the semicolon with a comma (if that isn't obvious and gets missed from the image). =TEXT(A1, "hh:mm:ss")